# How to make a table of symbols in report class?

Tags: nomenclature

I want to make a table of symbols in a report class. But, I don't know why, it's does not appear in my document. The code that I'm using is as follow.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nomencl} 
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
SOME TEXT \\

\vspace{6cm}
{\Large \textbf{My title}} \\
\vspace{3cm}
{\large \textbf{myself}} \\
\vspace*{\fill}
My city \\
Today
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{center}

\tableofcontents 

\newpage
\printnomenclature 

\nomenclature{$a$}{Some value}
\nomenclature{$b$}{Another value}

\chapter{Part A}
\lipsum

\par
\textbf{Below, you'll see my new equation:}

\begin{equation}
a = \frac{b}{c}
\end{equation}

\chapter{Part B}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you run  `makeindex` as said in the `nomencl` documentation (cf. *The Basics*)? If so, you should have a `.nls` file with the same base name as your document. If not, that would explain the absence of output from `\printnomenclature`.

Comment: @Eric, compile the LaTeX file with pdflatexmk and it will work.

Comment: @Anstudent I have Texmaker and this option is not available.

Comment: @frougon No, I don't. To tell you the truth, I don't understood this step cited by the `nomencl` documentation.

Comment: @Eric That is what @Mikochien put in his answer. If you don't understand, explain him precisely what you don't understand (you may need to run the given `makeindex` command from a terminal).

Comment: @frougon I answered him, but he does not replied back.

Comment: 2 hours doesn't count as “not replying back.” People may have a life beyond TeX.SE. You need to run the indicated command in a terminal. Use a search engine to find out how to run commands on your OS (keywords: terminal, console, command prompt, `cmd.exe` <-- the last one only if under Windows)

Answer (score 3):

Follow [this document of package nomencl](http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl/nomencl.pdf#subsection.2.1):

> Now put your file through LATEX. The command `\makenomenclature` will instruct LATEX  to open the nomenclature file *〈filename〉.nlo* corresponding to your LATEX file *〈filename〉.tex* and to write the information from your `\nomenclature` commands to this file.
>
> The next step is to invoke *MakeIndex*. You should instruct *MakeIndex* to use *〈filename〉.nlo* as your input file, use `nomencl.ist` as your style file and write output to the file *〈filename〉.nls*. How to do this depends on your implementation of MakeIndex. For most UNIX implementations you should write something like:
>
> `makeindex 〈filename〉.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o 〈filename〉.nls`
>
> Now you have the file *〈filename〉.nls* that contains your nomenclature list properly ordered. The last step is to invoke LATEX on your masterfile *〈filename〉.tex* once more.  It will input your.nls file and process it accordingly to the current options. That’s all!

Compile sequence (example with `pdflatex`):

```
pdflatex <filename>.tex
makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls
pdflatex <filename>.tex
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Nevertheless, I not understood whats mean "use `nomencl.ist` as your style file and write output to the file <filename>.nls". I also dont understood where I have to put
`makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls`
Can you help me in this? Thanks in advance!